# ReadTimeout value used in the FailoverOptions for redis.NewFailoverClient to connect to a redis sentinel doesn't seem to have an effect. Why?

Tags: go, redis, redis-sentinel, go-redis

Expected Behavior

If the read operation is taking more time than the ReadTimeout value, it should return an error.

Current Behavior

ReadTimeout exceeds, but no error is returned.

Steps to Reproduce

- Connect to a redis sentinel with a ReadTimeout value defined. When the value is smaller, it's easier to reproduce. In the example, I've used 30 microseconds
- Do a read operation which takes more than the ReadTimeout and observe the result

Code to reproduce:

```
    package main
    
    import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "time"
    )
    
    func main() {
    master := "mymaster"
    SentinelServers := []string{"localhost:26379"}
    Password := ""
    PoolSize := 9
    DB := 11
    client := redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions{
    MasterName: master,
    SentinelAddrs: SentinelServers,
    Password: Password,
    PoolSize: PoolSize,
    DB: DB,
    ReadTimeout: time.Duration(30) * time.Microsecond,
    })
    
    res, err := client.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Ping error %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
    
    key := "key2"
    value := "val2"
    err = client.Set(key, value, time.Duration(30)*time.Second).Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Writing error %s\n", err)
    }
    
    start := time.Now()
    val, err := client.Get(key).Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Reading error %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Cache read in %s\n", elapsed)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
    }
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/2305) on Github as well.